# How can I get a single tile of natural gas out of my greenhouse?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

In Oxygen Not Included my greenhouse has a single tile of natural gas that has settled on the bottom. Whenever it moves over a plant, the plant stops growing.

I have a strong force of oxygen coming in from one end of the room, but it is just not blowing the natural gas out for some reason. The pressure inside the room is 1700 and outside is 1400, so there should be good circulation, but for some reason the natural gas does not move.

Answer (score 2):

To remove it you would need to construct a Gas Pump in the room, which pumps into a Gas Filter. Then you could set the Gas Filter to filter Natural Gas, venting that outside the room and sending the Oxygen back into the room.

The second solution is to create a single tile empty space, in the same row as your farm tiles. This single space will eventually capture the Natural Gas as it sinks below Oxygen. [As shown in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_lvEELsvfY).

[image: Single tile gas gap]

Comment: I did try the low tile, but for some reason the natural gas never goes in there, it just floats around on top of the plants.

Comment: You might need to increase the Oxygen pressure.

Comment: I had a deoxydizer right under this room blowing into it. It was 1700g of oxygen per tile.